# Images not showing in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import

I'm following along with a Scrimba tutorial on React and I'm doing it on my own machine locally.
I have an image in my images folder within my src folder.
In my components folder I have a component called Card which is shown but why is my image only shown when I import it and not like the other two ways which are commented out?

Might be something stupid but I can't see it. Thanks all.
Just for clarity everything else works bar the image tags commented out.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Hero />
      <Card
        img="katie-zaferes.png"
        rating="5.0"
        reviewCount="6"
        country="USA"
        title="Life Lessons With Katie Zaferes"
        price={136}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Card.js**

```
import Star from "../images/star.png";
import Athlete from "../images/katie-zaferes.png";

const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img src={Athlete} alt="card-image" />
      {/* <img src="../images/katie-zaferes.png" alt="img" /> */}
      {/* <img src={`../images/${props.img}`} alt="card-image" /> */}

      <div className="card--stats">
        <img src={Star} alt="star" className="card--star" />
        <span>{props.rating}</span>
        <span className="gray">{props.reviewCount} •</span>
        <span className="gray">{props.country}</span>
      </div>

      <p>{props.title}</p>
      <p>
        <b>From $ {props.price} </b> / person
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured out it was an image path issue. I placed my 'images' folder in 'public'. I could then remove all imports and access them anywhere through `'/images/example.png'`.

Used in a component as shown below:

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img src={`/images/${props.img}`} alt="card" />

      <div className="card--stats">
        <img src="/images/star.png" alt="star" className="card--star" />
        <span>{props.rating}</span>
        <span className="gray">{props.reviewCount} • </span>
        <span className="gray">{props.country}</span>
      </div>

      <p>{props.title}</p>
      <p>
        <b>From $ {props.price} </b> / person
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you cant put the 'images' folder in 'public' because create-react-app doesn't let you, put your path as a string literal inside a **required** function, it worked for me

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img src={require(`../images/${props.img}`)} alt="card" />

      <div className="card--stats">
        <img src="/images/star.png" alt="star" className="card--star" />
        <span>{props.rating}</span>
        <span className="gray">{props.reviewCount} • </span>
        <span className="gray">{props.country}</span>
      </div>

      <p>{props.title}</p>
      <p>
        <b>From $ {props.price} </b> / person
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

This path works assuming you have your 'image' folder as a sibling to you 'component' folder

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the image you are trying to show on your App.js, you are giving your Card component a wrong path to find your image, your app needs to know where to find your "katie-zaferes.png" image, so the right way should be:

```html
<Card
  img='../images/katie-zaferes.png'
  ...
/>
```

(I'm assuming that your App.js and your Card.js files are on the same folder, in case they're not, you have to modify the path to match your /images/katie-zaferes.png)

Note: By the way, for your next questions here in StackOverflow, try to write your code directly on your post, using the Javascript/HTML/CSS button, never use images because it makes more work for people to answer your question/

Comment: Apologies. Fixed that, thanks. Added extra info if you can help.

Comment: Ok, i think i just understood your app ‍♂️. You are defining your image name on the App.js and then passing the image file name through props to your Card Component. Are you not getting the image displaying with `<img src={`../images/${props.img}`} alt="card-image" />`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Nope, that's not showing it at all and neither is the <img src="../images/katie-zaferes.png" alt="img" /> which I thought would have worked. Only the 'Athlete' import being used as src is working for some reason.

Comment: It's not your fault, i just need some sleep hahaha. Of course you want to reuse your Card component as many times you need, so i can recommend you to do the imports on your App.js like `import Athlete from "../images/katie-zaferes.png"` and then pass `img={Athlete}` as a prop into `<Card />`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured out it was a path issue more than anything else. (as shown in answer) Your method helped short term but not ideal having to import everything separately.

Comment: Why does my image disappear after visiting other links then returning?